# How to render a React material-ui components without any css?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, css-in-js

I want to render any given material-ui component, but with no default css - and style it myself.

Let's take the [TextField](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/) component.

By default it has a lot of classes applied:

```html
<div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root">
    <label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated">label</label>
    <div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl">
        <input class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to just render the HTML

```html
<div>
    <label>label</label>
    <div>
        <input>
    </div>
</div>
```

and provide my own css-in-js generated class names to any of the rendered elements.

How can I achieve that with any mui component?

Comment: Support for this is intended in v5 (still months away), but there is no simple way to achieve this now. See this issue for details: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/6218.